# My JSON response returns the wrong format. Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!-- [Synt"... is not valid JSON

Tags: json, ajax, symfony

I want to display in AJAX a list of people to add to these friends in a Symfony 6.2 project.

At first everything worked but recently the error quoted in the title is displayed when the event is triggered.

I have already tried several solutions found on the internet, but the error still persists. I have restored my code and show it to you.

First the Twig files with the  in the  that contains the EventListener

liste.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Vos amis{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Vos amis</h1>
    <form id="recherche">
        Rechercher :
        <input type="text" name="pseudo">
    </form>
    <ul id="ajoutsAmis">
        {{ include('amis/_ajoutAmis.html.twig') }}
    </ul>
    <ul id="listeAmis">
        {{ include('amis/_listeAmis.html.twig') }}
    </ul>

    {% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/script_amis.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

_ajoutAmis.html.twig

```
{% if ajoutAmis != null %}
<h1>Personnes trouvées</h1>
    {% for a in ajoutAmis %}
        <li><p>{{a.pseudo}}</p><button id="{{a.pseudo}}" class="btn_ajouter">Ajouter</button></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

_listeAmis.html.twig

```
{% if amis %}
    {% for a in amis %}
        <li>{{a.pseudo}}</li> 
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    Vous n'avez pas encore de contact.
{% endif %}
```

The AmisController (FriendController)

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\UtilisateurRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class AmisController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/contacts', name: 'app_amis')]
    public function index(UtilisateurRepository $utilisateurRepository, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request): Response
    {
        if($this->getUser()){
            $amis = ($this->getUser())->getAmis();

            //On vérifie si on a une requête AJAX et on exécute notre requête SQL
            $ajoutAmis = null;
            if($request->get('ajax') == 'recherche' && $request->get('pseudo') != null){
                $ajoutAmis = $utilisateurRepository->findBySearchFriend($this->getUser(), $request->get('pseudo'));
                
                return new JsonResponse(['content' => $this->renderView('amis/_ajoutAmis.html.twig', [
                    'ajoutAmis' => $ajoutAmis
                ])]);
            }

            if($request->get('ajax') == 'ajoutami'){
                $ami = $utilisateurRepository->findOneByPseudo($request->get('pseudo'));
                $user = $this->getUser();
                $user->addAmi($ami);
                $amis = $user->getAmis();
                $entityManager->persist($user);
                $entityManager->flush();

                return new JsonResponse(['content' => $this->renderView('amis/_listeAmis.html.twig', [
                    'amis' => $amis,
                ])]);
            }

            return $this->render('amis/liste.html.twig', [
                'amis' => $amis,
                'ajoutAmis' => $ajoutAmis
            ]);
        }
        else{
            $this->addFlash('danger','Vous devez être connecté pour accèder à cette page.');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
        }
    }
}
```

The method findBySearchFriend() in UtilisateurRepository (UserRepository)

```
public function findBySearchFriend(Utilisateur $user, $value = null): array
   {
       return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
           ->andWhere('u.pseudo LIKE :val')
           ->setParameter('val', '%'.$value.'%')
           ->andWhere('u != :user')
           ->setParameter('user', $user)
           ->andWhere(':user.amis != u')
           ->setParameter('user', $user)
           ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
           ->setMaxResults(10)
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();
   }
```

The script JS

```
window.onload = () => {

    //PARTIE RECHERCHE EN AJAX

    const RechercheForm = document.querySelector('#recherche');

    document.querySelector('#recherche input').addEventListener('input', () => {
        // ici on intercepte quand l'utilisateur écrit
        // On récupère les données du formulaire
        const Form = new FormData(RechercheForm);

        //On fabrique la "queryString" (paramètre de l'url)
        const Params = new URLSearchParams();

        Form.forEach((value, key) => {
            Params.append(key, value);
        });

        // On récupère l'url active
        const Url = new URL(window.location.href);

        // On lance la requête AJAX
        fetch(Url.pathname + "?" + Params.toString() + "&ajax=recherche", {
            headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
            }
        }).then(response => 
            response.json()
        ).then(data => {
            // On vient chercher la zone de contenu
            const content = document.querySelector('#ajoutsAmis');
            // On remplace le contenu
            content.innerHTML = data.content;
            //On associe les boutons .btn_ajouter a la méthode ajouter
            document.querySelectorAll('.btn_ajouter').forEach(btn => {
                btn.addEventListener('click', ajoutAmis);
            })
        })
        .catch(e => alert(e));
    });

    //PARTIE AJOUT D'AMI EN AJAX

    function ajoutAmis(){
        //On récupère le pseudo
        const Url = new URL(window.location.href);

        fetch(Url.pathname + '?pseudo=' + this.previousSibling.textContent + '&ajax=ajoutami', {
            headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
            }
        }).then( response => 
            response.json()
        ).then(data => {
            this.parentNode.remove();
            const content = document.querySelector('#listeAmis');
            content.innerHTML = data.content;
        })
        .catch(e => alert(e))
    }
}
```

And the JSON Response (it's long a write only few lines) :

```
<!-- [Syntax Error] line 0, col 88: Error: Expected =, &lt;, &lt;=, &lt;&gt;, &gt;, &gt;=, !=, got '.' (500 Internal Server Error) -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <title>[Syntax Error] line 0, col 88: Error: Expected =, &lt;, &lt;=, &lt;&gt;, &gt;, &gt;=, !=, got '.' (500 Internal Server Error)</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="data:image/png;base64,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">
        <style>/* This file is based on WebProfilerBundle/Resources/views/Profiler/profiler.css.twig.
   If you make any change in this file, verify the same change is needed in the other file. */
:root {
    --font-sans-serif: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    --page-background: #f9f9f9;
    --color-text: #222;
    /* when updating any of these colors, do the same in toolbar.css.twig */
    --color-success: #4f805d;
    --color-warning: #a46a1f;
    --color-error: #b0413e;
    --color-muted: #999;
    --tab-background: #fff;
    --tab-color: #444;
    --tab-active-background: #666;
    --tab-active-color: #fafafa;
    --tab-disabled-background: #f5f5f5;
    --tab-disabled-color: #999;
    --metric-value-background: #fff;
    --metric-value-color: inherit;
    --metric-unit-color: #999;
    --metric-label-background: #e0e0e0;
    --metric-label-color: inherit;
    --table-border: #e0e0e0;
    --table-background: #fff;
    --table-header: #e0e0e0;
    --trace-selected-background: #F7E5A1;
    --tree-active-background: #F7E5A1;
    --exception-title-color: var(--base-2);
    --shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(128, 128, 128, .2);
    --border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    --background-error: var(--color-error);
    --highlight-comment: #969896;
    --highlight-default: #222222;
    --highlight-keyword: #a71d5d;
    --highlight-string: #183691;
    --base-0: #fff;
    --base-1: #f5f5f5;
    --base-2: #e0e0e0;
    --base-3: #ccc;
    --base-4: #666;
    --base-5: #444;
    --base-6: #222;
}
```

It works without these two lines in the queryBuilder :

```
     ->andWhere(':user.amis != u')
     ->setParameter('user', $user)
```

He didn't like the ':user.amis'

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems that in your question you have given us all the code that is not relevant to the problem but not the JSON itself. Please not that the error is in the JSON so that is where you should be looking to find the error. Where has this JSON come from? I suspect that the TWIG that you have provided is irrelevant to your problem and  it just leaves people more to read.

Comment: It seems from the query that it is the findBySearchFriend method that is having the problem.
Regarding the JSON, that's why my question is asked. I edit my topic for more details

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem finally, this is the new queryBuilder :

```
public function findBySearchFriend(Utilisateur $user, $value = null): array
   {
        $amis = $user->getAmis();

       return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
           ->andWhere('u.pseudo LIKE :val')
           ->setParameter('val', '%'.$value.'%')
           ->andWhere('u != :user')
           ->setParameter('user', $user)
           ->andWhere('u NOT IN (:amis)')
           ->setParameter('amis', $amis)  
           ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
           ->setMaxResults(10)
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();
   }
```

And I had 'if(Input.value){...}' to my script.